# Flume Distribution

Tags: apache, flume-ng, bigdata

From Apache Flume 1.6 Official website , I find flume is **distributed**. But Master-slave architecture has been deprecated after Flume 1.x. How does flume distribute the work? I have flume installed on two hosts via Hortonworks . I feel like  running 2 seperate flume on two different machines. Can someone help me understand its distribution. What if I have a HttpAgent on Host A and Host B with same source and sink configured? Will there be replication of the input data or flume co-ordinates? Kindly correct my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Flume has kind of "do it yourself" distribution type. Check the [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#setting-multi-agent-flow) for some details and examples.

> What if I have a HttpAgent on Host A and Host B with same source and sink configured?

It will replicate the data unless your source has no "exactly once" delivery semantic